# Remove charactor/digit from string if string length greater than some value

Tags: php

using PHP, How can i remove the rest of character if `sting_Len` is greater than 6 for example i have `600275L` and i want to end up like `600275` but only if greater than 6 digit.
i used the following code to to extract value starts with `600`, i want update it to work for the above condition, Thank you

```
    if((substr($key, 0, 3) == "600") && ($row['ItemClass']==3)) 
    {
     $assy = $key;
     $rout = "Assy";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to limit it to six characters, then you should just be able to use `substr` for this without checking the length. If you write:

```
$string = 'abcdefg';
$string = substr($string, 0, 6);
```

then `$string` will equal `'abcdef'`.

But if `$string` is shorter than 6 characters, it will just return the entire string. So if you write:

```
$string = 'abc';
$string = substr($string, 0, 6);
```

then `$string` will equal `'abc'`.

You can see this in the PHP manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php#refsect1-function.substr-examples).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following logic

```
if(strlen($code) > 6) { echo substr($code, 0, 6); }
```